# How to organise REST endpoints for a drop-wizard application?

Tags: rest, dropwizard, hateoas

I am new to dropwizard and REST.

My sample application is a order viewing system. Currently, I am working on a functionality where the UI page consists of set of order search criteria, search button, and link to download the search result as CSV. Download link is displayed only after the successful search. The application has to write the search result to a CSV file and the file location returned will be used to download the file.

I need help in organising the endpoints for this.

Initially, I thought of an end point `GET` - `/orders` - `text/JSON` with search criteria passed in as query params. But, since I will be actually creating the CSV for every GET request, I am wondering if I am violating the HATEOAS rest constraint for the GET (resource should not be created). Or, since the actual resource is Order and not the CSV, is it ok to have the endpoint as GET?

Or, do I need multiple endpoints adhering to the REST constraints and conventions interacting with each other to produce the required result? 
Like:

1.`POST` - `/orders/csv`  - `text/json` (file name) : creates the CSV file of orders and returns the JSON of file name.

2.`GET` `/orders/csv/<file_name>`: gets the file to download.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: HATEOAS are just further links a client can use contained in the returned response. These links just describe the admissible actions on the current state of the resource. Creating a new File via a GET request is something completely different. Usually this can be compared with search form on HTML pages which are sent usually as POST request to the server

Comment: To your actual question: this can be solved by a single endpoint (`/search/orders` f.e) where you send a post request containing the search criterias to the server. This will trigger the CSV creation on the server. The server sends a 201 Created response back to the client containing the location header pointing to the resource (maybe also the new content); if the processing requires more time also an `202 Accepted` return code also with the location header can be returned. The client can then use the URI returned in the location header to retrieve the content (inf not already returned)